# UndefinedMetricWarning: No positive samples in y_true, true positive value should be meaningless UndefinedMetricWarning)

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I got this warning

> UndefinedMetricWarning: No positive samples in y_true, true positive
>   value should be meaningless  UndefinedMetricWarning)

Do you have any idea what it means?

Comment: This happens when using sklearn's `roc_curve` function on data which either has all 0s or all 1s.

Comment: @CMCDragonkai and how this problem can be solved?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This means that all the values in y_true are zeros, which means there is no positive class records in the given dataset.

Try the following to understand the distribution of classes in your dataset.

```
from collections import Counter
Counter(y_true) # y_true must be your labels
```

Answer (score 2):

For me, I got this error when I erroneously passed a `pos_label` param.

The [docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.roc_curve.html#sklearn.metrics.roc_curve) say the `y_true` param should be "binary labels. If labels are not either {-1, 1} or {0, 1}, then `pos_label` should be explicitly given."

However my scores happened to be all `0` and `1` omitting the `pos_label` parameter solved it for me!